# How do I make the questions appear in random order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have made a quiz using Obj.C. What I want to to do is make the questions appear in random order. I have tried many methods but so far I have failed.

```
+ (NSArray *) myArray
{
    static NSArray *theArray;
    if (!theArray)
    {
        theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    }
    return theArray;
}

+ (NSArray *) questions {
    return @[
             @{@"question":
```

Comment: Please post more code. And don't post the incomplete code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I generate a random array from another array.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[object1, object2, object3, ..., objectN];
NSMutableArray *arrayToTakeItemsFrom = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:myArray];
NSMutableArray *randomOrderedArray = [NSMutableArray new];

while (arrayToTakeItemsFrom.count > 0) {
    int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(arrayToTakeItemsFrom.count);
    MyObjectClass *swapObject = [arrayToTakeItemsFrom objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    [arrayToTakeItemsFrom removeObject:swapObject];
    [randomOrderedArray addObject:swapObject];
}

//Now randomOrderedArray has everything myArray has in it but in a random order, and always works for any size array including an empty array
```

Comment: Don't use `arc4random() % x`. Use `arc4random_uniform(x)`.

Comment: And an easier way to get `arrayToRakeItemsFrom` is to do `= [myArray mutableCopy];`.

Comment: Those are two excellent points. I did not know about `arc4random_uniform(x)`, thanks for teaching me something new! The only reason I explicitly allocate a new `NSMutableArray` is to make it easier to read. It might be a little longer, but it's more in line with what most new developers will understand.